# QGIS layout size

Tags: qgis, layouts

I am working on a layout which is to be printed on A0 paper size on QGIS. However I cannot find the A0 paper size choice under Layout>Page Setup.

[image]

Does anyone know why the A0 option is not there? A0 is a standard map size, is it not supported by QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm that A0 is supported by QGIS:

[image]

but could be not supported by your printer driver. ;)

Please check and see if using the same printer (i.e. printer driver) your computer shows A0 among the available formats from another program (for example GIMP, or LibreOffice).

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind. it looks like the paper sizes are set to whatever printer you have active. My default printer is of course not capable of printing out A0 paper. I fixed this issue by going under Layout>Print, changing my default printer to a PDF printer. I was then able to see A0 paper size since it is supported by my PDF printer.

Comment: You can also choose "custom" page size, and manually input the page height and width. Page size A0 is 841 x 1189 mm (33.1 x 46.8 in).